# connect my angular application to sharepoint to get data

Tags: angular, sharepoint

I'm new in this context, I want to know if there some solution to get resources from my SharePoint folder, I need to list all resources that I have in the folder, I'm working with angular, I  couldn't implement any function, thank you for read

Comment: The information which you shared is very limited for us to comment. However, it seems you should explore if SharePoint has exposed any APIs. If so , your best option is to retrieve data from Sharpoint by Angular application by interacting with that API.

Comment: i just need an example of implementation where i make the connection with a folder in my sharepoint, thank you :), have a great day